# External screen flickering at native resolution, but not lower resolution, and only in GUI, not console

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have a slightly older HP ProBook Laptop with integrated Intel graphics running Ubuntu 18.04 on kernel 4.19.0 and the external screen (DisplayPort connection) gets tearing and then goes dark for a second and then comes back.  It keeps doing this over and over again and it's impossible to do any work on it.  Things that stop this from happening:

- Lowering the resolution from 1920x1080 to 1600x900
- Switching to console mode

This issue does not affect the integrated display.

Things that I have tried that have **not** had any effect:

- Increasing the amount of video memory in the BIOS
- Setting `vm.swappiness=15` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` (from default of 60)
- Installing and upgrading `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package
- Trying different environments (same problem with Unity, Wayland, Gnome, etc.)
- Plugging the monitor directly into the laptop or via docking station
- Swapping out monitors entirely
- Adding `"TearFree" "true"` to the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file
- Upgrading kernel to 4.19.60

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.